# Oracle keep dense_rank with manual pivoting

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a table that records event dates per ID. Each event has a type, and there may be zero or more registered dates per event type and ID.

I need to produce a resultset with each distinct ID, along with the first start date, the last repair date and the last end date. This is simple. But I also need to select the reference code with each record. This part I can't seem to handle in the same query.

```
with example_data as(
   select 'A' as id, 'START'  as t, date '2017-01-01' as d, '18' as ref from dual union all
   select 'A' as id, 'WHATEV' as t, date '2017-01-02' as d, '12' as ref from dual union all
   select 'A' as id, 'CRASH'  as t, date '2017-01-05' as d, '17' as ref from dual union all
   select 'A' as id, 'REPAIR' as t, date '2017-01-06' as d, '01' as ref from dual union all
   select 'A' as id, 'CRASH'  as t, date '2017-01-10' as d, '20' as ref from dual union all
   select 'A' as id, 'REPAIR' as t, date '2017-01-11' as d, '07' as ref from dual union all
   select 'A' as id, 'END'    as t, date '2017-01-12' as d, '14' as ref from dual union all
   select 'B' as id, 'START'  as t, date '2017-01-01' as d, '24' as ref from dual union all
   select 'B' as id, 'END'    as t, date '2017-01-10' as d, '28' as ref from dual
-- Primary key(id, t, d)   
)
select id
      ,min(case when t = 'START'  then d end) as start_date 
      ,max(case when t = 'END'    then d end) as end_date
      ,max(case when t = 'REPAIR' then d end) as repair_date
  from example_data
 where t in('START', 'END', 'REPAIR')
 group 
    by id;


ID  START_DATE  END_DATE  REPAIR_DATE
-- ----------  ---------- -----------
A   2017-01-01  2017-01-12 2017-01-11
B   2017-01-01  2017-01-10
```

Here is my attempt at including the ref code from the corresponding record, but for some reason the repair_ref is null.

```
select id
      ,min(case when t = 'START'  then ref end) keep (dense_rank first order by d asc)  as start_ref 
      ,min(case when t = 'END'    then ref end) keep (dense_rank first order by d desc) as end_ref
      ,min(case when t = 'REPAIR' then ref end) keep (dense_rank first order by d desc) as repair_ref
  from example_data
 where t in('START', 'END', 'REPAIR')
 group 
    by id;
```

Here is the output from my attempt. I was expecting repair_ref = '07' for id=A. What am I doing wrong?

```
ID START_REF END_REF REPAIR_REF
-- --------- ------- ----------
A  18        14 
B  24        28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.  The problem is that the `keep` is looking at all the records.  So, I think you can do:

```
select id,
       min(case when t = 'START'  then d end) keep (dense_rank first 
             order by (case when t = 'START'  then d end) asc)             as start_date,
       max(case when t = 'END'    then d end) keep (dense_rank first 
             order by (case when t = 'END'    then d end) desc nulls last) as end_date,
       max(case when t = 'REPAIR' then d end) keep (dense_rank first 
             order by (case when t = 'REPAIR' then d end) desc nulls last) as repair_date
from example_data
 where t in ('START', 'END', 'REPAIR')
 group by id;
```

Comment: I just edited to change the ordering clause for `start_date` (for this one, the OP needed the earliest date rather than the latest) - and I formatted a little so it can be read without scrolling. In my opinion this is indeed the correct solution (and the correct explanation of why the OP's attempt failed).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. Just one followup-question since the real problem is slightly more complicated: If I need to order by more columns, I just repeat the pattern above (case when t = 'xxx' then ref end) ? Or does it change if ordering by multiple columns?
As an example, think of an extra timestamp column part of the key to indicate versions

Comment: @Ronnis . . . You can order by more than one column.  The first key is probably all you need to be sure that the right `t` value is the first in the sort.  You just have to remember that the `keep` expression is on *all* the data, but you want a results for only one type.